# Tag synonym proposal: alternative and alternative-words

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[Alternative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative):

> This tag is for questions about choosing different or alternative words or phrases.

[Alternative-Words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-words):

> Used to request words that can be used in place of another word because they have essentially the same meaning.

Should these tags be merged or distinguished (with cross-links in descriptions)?

Answer (score 3):

I kind of feel that both of these should be merged with [synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms). I guess the word "synonym" may tend to connote a single word, but it can also refer to a phrase or expression. In any case, users can make it clear which kind of synonyms they're looking for by adding the tags [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) or [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests).

The only possible downside I see to this is that it would make it harder for people who want to "favorite" only questions requesting alternative words, and not other questions about synonyms such as "what are the differences between these synonyms." There are only 2 followers of the tag "alternative," however.

Stats:

- [alternative-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-words): 0 followers, 64 questions
- [alternative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative): 2 followers, 181 questions
- [synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms):  25 followers, 1.7k questions

Comment: I think *synonym* generally seeks the **same** meaning (and in many cases should be solved by a thesaurus) while *alternative* or *alternative-words* seek a meaning that differs in some specified way.

Comment: @WBT: well, "synonyms" is a well-established tag, so I don't think we should restrict it to off-topic questions (which is what questions that are best solved by a thesaurus would be). Here are some examples that I think would fit just as well in any of these tags: [Equivalent for “personify” that's not human-specific](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/271044), [What's a better word for “evoke” in the phrase “evoke a realization”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269667), [Non-malevolent synonym of envy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308296)

Answer (score 0):

Came to suggest the removal of these two tags and found this proposal to merge them together.

*Five years* after this original proposal was made, neither [alternative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative) or [alternative-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-words) have been used whatsoever. It seems everyone still uses [synonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym).

I suggest one of:

1. Remove both of the "Alternative" tags as they're unused
2. Moderate/edit posts to start making use of the "Alternative" tags when appropriate, to show publicly that they're to be used when relevant

I would favour (1), as I'm not convinced there is a difference between the "Synonym" tag and the two "Alternative" tags, or indeed any difference between the two "Alternative" tags.

The Synonym tag description states:

> A synonym is a word that means the same, or almost the same thing, as another word.

That is surely describing an "alternative" word?

Comment: Ah it appears they were merged. I posted this as when using the "Synonym" tag in a post it mentions the "Alt" tags. And I searched for the "Alt" tags which both appear in search with "0 questions".

Comment: I think there are no posts with alternative/alternative-word tags. When someone starts typing tag description "alternative" the system automatically substitutes it with "synonym" tag.